# Is it possible to partially auto-fill inputs in bash?

Tags: bash, input

Let's say I need a user input in a bash shell script. For example:

```
What is your name: |
```

(`|` is the cursor)

Instead of a blank entry space, is it possible to auto-fill the input for the user, then he or she could continue to change the input if needed and press enter?

```
What is your name: Mathew|
What is your name: Mat|
What is your name: Matthew|
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, using `read`:

```
read -e -p "What is your name: " -i "Mathew" RESULT
echo $RESULT
```

Will give you:

```
Enter your name: Mathew
```

And you can edit or just press enter and $RESULT will hold the value